# PyQt5 : How to check My textbox is empty or not by passing reference/Value?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Want to check textbox1 is empty or not ? How to pass reference ?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class My_Process(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.textbox = QLineEdit()

    def checkstatus(self):
        if self.textbox.text() =="":
            print("Empty Value Not Allowed")
            self.textbox.setFocus()
        else:
            print(" Your Text : ",textbox.text())
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Mainprg(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.tb = My_Process(self)
        self.text1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.text2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.text1.setGeometry(100,100,300,30)
        self.text2.setGeometry(100,200,300,30)
        self.text1.editingFinished.connect(self.tb.checkstatus)

        self.showMaximized()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Mainprg()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it's confusing to make a new class to do your validation. I would make `checkstatus` a method of Mainprg:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Mainprg(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.text1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.text2 = QLineEdit(self)

        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 600, 450)

        self.text1.setGeometry(100,100,300,30)
        self.text2.setGeometry(100,200,300,30)
        self.text1.editingFinished.connect(self.checkstatus)

        self.show()

    def checkstatus(self):
        if self.text1.text() == "":
            print("Empty Value Not Allowed")
            self.text1.setFocus()
        else:
            print(" Your Text : ", self.text1.text())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Mainprg()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Above code works, but probably you want something more generic for more than one QLineEdit. There's no really good way to pass arguments to PyQt connect statements, so most people use lambdas:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Mainprg(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.text1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.text2 = QLineEdit(self)

        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 600, 450)

        self.text1.setGeometry(100,100,300,30)
        self.text2.setGeometry(100,200,300,30)
        self.text1.editingFinished.connect(lambda: self.checkstatus(self.text1))
        self.text2.editingFinished.connect(lambda: self.checkstatus(self.text2))

        self.show()

    def checkstatus(self, widget):
        if widget.text() == "":
            print("Empty Value Not Allowed")
            widget.setFocus()
        else:
            print(" Your Text : ", widget.text())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Mainprg()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code works more the way you want to, but you'll run into a problem if text1 is empty and you try to move to text2. You'll get a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" because the `checkstatus` method gets repeatedly called. To prevent this, you have to do one of the following:

1. make a handler for the QApplication's focusChanged event
2. create a QValidator and apply it to your widgets using `setValidator()`

If you are determined to make a new class, you can try this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class My_Process():
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.textbox = widget

    def checkstatus(self):
        if self.textbox.text() == "":
            print("Empty Value Not Allowed")
            self.textbox.setFocus()
        else:
            print(" Your Text : ", self.textbox.text())

class Mainprg(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.text1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.text2 = QLineEdit(self)

        self.process = My_Process(self.text1)

        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 600, 450)

        self.text1.setGeometry(100,100,300,30)
        self.text2.setGeometry(100,200,300,30)
        self.text1.editingFinished.connect(self.process.checkstatus)

        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Mainprg()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To pass `text1` to the class, you add an argument to the **init** method.

Comment: Hai @bfris

I am a leaner and I Want to know, how to pass reference in PyQt5 Widgets. In my code , I create two classes one is My_process and another one is Mainprg. Now I want to pass reference from Mainprg to My_Process and do something. But i Get

 **if self.textbox.text() =="":
AttributeError: 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'textbox**

Comment: See updated answer. The last block of code passes a reference to My_Process class.

Comment: Hai @bfris,  How to get/returns the name of the widget which currently has the focus

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61690446/9705687)